# Is there a rounded /æ/? Is there a Near-open front rounded vowel?

Tags: ipa, vowels, conlang

Okay, so I was just doing a bit of conlanging, and I was coming up with a verb ending /æɸ/. Because of the way I have begun this, /ɸ~ʍ/ are interchangeable. When I first tried saying /æʍ]/ I accidentally rounded the /æ/, which is 100% natural and to be expected. I am currently writing this rounded /æ/ as /æ̹/--it's the only thing I can do. This rounded /æ/ is honestly the most repulsive sound I have ever heard in my life, but I like it.

I know that there are hundreds, maybe even thousands of vowels theoretically, but it seems like this one would have a general symbol for itself. I am having enough trouble finding a "complete" I.P.A. chart, as it is, with all of the symbols that have been made for the I.P.A. Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "[A]ll of the symbols that have been made for the I.P.A." are on the official IPA chart. Modifiers provide the ability to fill in the gaps, but letters with diacritics have no canonical values, so e.g. how retracted the retracted diacritic is supposed to make a letter is undetermined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the [official IPA chart](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/sites/default/files/IPA2005_1000px.png). As you can see, the front round vowel in that region is the open front round vowel [ɶ], the round counterpart of [a], and [æ] has no round counterpart. Note that symbols are not exact vowels, and [a] can be located in a number positions in that general vicinity (as one can see by comparing placement in specific languages, in IPA descriptions). So using [ɶ] for a rounder version of [æ] is consistent with how symbols are used (though use of [œ] probably would not be, on the assumption that the vowel is closer to canonical [ɶ] than it is to [œ].

Comment: The trickier part is: Is there any attested language, that uses a phoneme /Œ/ or rounded /æ̹/? I don't know any.

Comment: Clicking on the Wikipedia symbol of /Œ/ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_rounded_vowel) yields Danish, Stockholm Swedish and Weert dialect of Limburgish (allophone), and Amstetten dialect of German (phoneme)...:)

Comment: Add of course that while IPA calls [a] a open front vowel, most people use it for the open *central* vowel, and use [æ] for the open front vowel. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a ligature of (ɔ + e) being used unofficially. maybe that

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — preferably with references to credible sources.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the close-mid back vowels, rounded (ɤ) and unrounded (o), become mid back vowels by being lowered by the lowered diacritic (◌̞), becoming ɤ̞ and o̞. So the open-mid front rounded vowel (œ) is above where the near-open front rounded vowel should be, the near-open front rounded vowel can be seen as "œ̞."

It can be "æ̹," along with another, "ɶ̝."